# Can I install Ubuntu on my Asus Fonepad?

Tags: android, asus, tablet

I don't need Ubuntu phone, I'm just interested in running Ubuntu since I use the device more as a computer than a phone (it is not my personal telephone).

It has an Intel chip so I'm thinking it wouldn't be too hard?  I know this has been asked, but its been a while. Any thoughts?

Comment: I too want to install ubuntu on my Fonepad 7 (ME175CG). But observing the speed of the Intel Atom processor that came with this, I'm doubtful that it can handle ubuntu (unless ubuntu-phone is optimized enough for small devices like the way Android OS is).

Answer (score 1):

Not currently, but there is a petition asking ASUS to [unlock the bootloader](http://www.change.org/en-GB/petitions/asus-issue-a-bootloader-unlocker-for-the-asus-fonepad-me371mg) (change.org) and allow development on the device.

Comment: Why is the petition closed now? Has ASUS already released source-code for their bootloader?